# Does bash have a color command, as seen in MS-Windows CMD?

Tags: linux, bash

There is a command in Microsoft's `cmd`, called `color`.
I know that, in `bash`, there are special characters that allows you, during the echos, to change the text colors. As well I do know that in ubuntu you can edit the parameters of the terminal setting a "style" going inside the config, editing it and applying it with mouse under the menus.

What I ask is, if there exists under debian, ubuntu and centOS something very simple like:

```
color 1b
```

so that the console turns from:

[image]

to

[image]

Comment: It is unclear as to if you are asking how to do it in Debian etc, or in Microsoft's Windows' CMD.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I posted the screenshot of it being done in windows because I know how to do it in windows but not in linux. Also this is unix stack exchange otherwise I would have gone to a windows forum / stack exchange..

Comment: Sorry I thought you were asking about bash in MS-Windows. I will edit you question to make it clear, for you.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor ok but I have edited the title in a clearer way.. in case leave it as it :)

Comment: Bash has no notion as such of colors etc - this is the realm of the terminal (which used to be a real device, but these days usually is emulated in software).  So it is just a question of finding a program that will do what you want that can be started from bash.

Comment: setterm, part of util-linux

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do this.

One way is by using `tput`:

`tput setab 4` sets the background color to blue. To set the foreground color, use `tput setaf`.

Another way is by using raw ANSI escapes, here is a good documentation: https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

Comment: It actually does something however just the written text changes, what about the full background like in windows cmd?

Comment: I believe this requires clearing the screen with `clear` or `CTRL + L`

Comment: @user3450548 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/474924/308316, the second part (about xterm-like terminals)

Comment: @user3450548 to answer your question directly this should set the background as in the 2nd picture: `printf '\e]11;#000080\a'`

Comment: Everything you do with escape sequences you can do more portably with `tput`.

Comment: @roaima No you can't. Please read the Note: from my linked answer.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that none of this really has anything to do with bash.  Escape sequences, tput, and so on will work from any shell, while none of them will work if the terminal emulator you're using doesn't support color changing.

Answer (score 5):

The command `setterm` can be used:

```
setterm -background blue
```

or

```
setterm -ba blue
```

This uses standard ECMA-48 control sequences and will actually work with many (but not all) terminal emulators. (Contrary to the manual, it does not in fact use terminfo for this option.)  ECMA-48 includes the notion of a *default colour* for both background and foreground which one can change to with `default`:

```
setterm --background default
```

To change the default colour, add the `--store` option (which emits a control sequence that only works with the Linux kernel's built-in terminal emulator, however):

```
setterm --background red --store
```

See `man setterm` and `setterm --help` for more details.

Comment: Just like with the `tput setab` from the accepted answer, calling either `reset` or temporarily setting the background with `printf 'foo\e[41mB\e[mar\n'` will wipe that setting.

Answer (score 4):

With `xterm`-like terminal emulators, you can use:

```
xtermcontrol --bg blue
```

(`blue` or any color specification supported by `XParseColor(3x)`).

That actually sends a `\33]11;blue\7` sequence, so you can do the same with:

```
printf '\33]11;%s\a' blue
```

See [Operating System Commands, in the XTerm Control Sequences document](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Operating-System-Commands) for details.