# Is there a way to change font color in the ubuntu server 21.04 console?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, console

I am trying to change the font colour in the console. I know it's easy to change it in the terminal emulator. But isit possible to change the colour of the font in the console ? I am using zsh by the way.

Comment: By console, you mean the monitor and keyboard connected directly to the physical machine?

Comment: I mean the TTY console not the terminal

Comment: I’m not suggesting a duplicate since I have a hammer here, but [How to set the background color of the Linux console screen?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/474502/86440) should give you all the ingredients you need (for foreground colours, use codes between 30 and 37 included; see [List of ANSI color escape sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4842424/4500798) for details).

Comment: This is for the console right? The tty? Not the terminal emulator from the xfce or gnome gui

Comment: See the title, “of the console screen”; the top-voted answer covers both.