How can I get tput to fill the whole background without leaving a border?
I'm using bash in cygwin on a Windows laptop. I'd like to be able to change the background color of my terminal to green (actual color irrelevant) and to do that I can use either of these commands:

tput setb 2; echo
printf '\e]11;#00FF00\a'

For more info on what that printf is doing, see how-to-set-the-background-color-of-the-linux-console-screen and the specific use of 11 for background is documented on page 34 of https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.pdf (Ps = 1 0 → Change VT100 text foreground color to Pt. and Ps = 1 1 → Change VT100 text background color to Pt.)
The printf immediately changes the bacground of the whole terminal while the tput just sets the color for what is typed next, hence the echo to start on the next empty line, but I don't care much about that. What I do most care about is the following:
The tput leaves a small border in the original background color (pale beige, set by the "Options" GUI I get by clicking on the top-left of the terminal) as can be seen in this image (the pale grey around the left/bottom of the image is my Windows desktop color):

The printf changes the color of the border (it's a lighter shade of green from tput's but that's irrelevant):

but it does not change the area of the background that was set by tput unless I first re-initialize what my original tput did with tput init; echo and then execute the printf:

I can just use the printf to get what I want as long as I don't use tput setb first but I'd prefer to only use tput setb if I can for portability so - why is tput leaving a small border of the existing background color and is there any way to tell tput to set the background color in a way that does not leave that small border?
I'd also like to know if there's a way to have tput set the whole terminal background immediately, as the printf does, rather than after the next string I type, but that's not nearly as important as getting rid of that border.
Additional info now that @MarcusMüller gave me the hint in a comment that this might be a mintty issue -
I see this same behavior when I use git bash from Windows on a different machine. They apparently both use mintty as the terminal emulator. Since I have to log into many different Windows machines and use cygwin or git bash, I'd like to be able to solve this problem without having to change terminal emulator every time I use one of those machines (I'm not even sure if/how I could do that). In fact, if it came down to changing terminal emulator to solve the tput problem, I'd just use the printf approach instead.
I found at set-border-width-for-mintty-window-on-cygwin-windows-10 a way to control the border width from ~/.minttyrc by setting the Padding variable and if I update it to say:
Padding=0

then that does work around the above tput problem but

That'd mean I'd have to change the .minttyrc on every machine I log into and restart the terminal afterwards, and
When I open the "Options" GUI to change anything about the terminal then save it, it overwrites that .minttyrc file and removes the Padding setting

so I still would like to find some way to simply tell tput to fill that "padding" area just like it does the rest of the background.
@Vilinkameni also points out in a comment that with the above tput in a mintty and MSYS2 MINGW64 terminal, any ANSI SGR color switching by a subsequent ls --color or other command that uses colors will effectively reset the color again. That does not happen if I use the above printf so I may ask about that in a subsequent question.
See also "Changing colours" towards the bottom https://code.google.com/archive/p/mintty/wikis/Tips.wiki#Changing_colours for more information on the above printf and other things related to mintty. My $TERM value is xterm.

that is an artifact of the terminal emulator you're using, it seems; might simply be a bug you should report. Not sure which one that is, Ed! (is it still mintty?) It's been ages since I used Cygwin, so I really can't claim I speak from recent experience, but in my memory the terminal emulator was … basic, and that's overstating the comfort it brings. Is using a different terminal emulator an option to you?

@MarcusMüller yes, it's mintty. I added some info about that to the bottom of my question now, thanks. If it came down to changing terminal emulator to solve the tput problem, I'd just use the printf approach instead.

want to write that as answer to your own question? By the way, you can try Alacritty as alternative terminal emulator if you're working on Windows 11 or a Windows 10 updated in the last 4.5 years.

@MarcusMüller thanks to your hint about mintty, I did find a way to control that border ("Padding") size to work around the problem, but I'm still looking for a tput option or other simple command-line solution so I'll hold off on posting the Padding=0 workaround as an "answer" until if/when I don't get what I'd consider a real answer using tput or similar.

@MarcusMüller I can't install any software on any machine at work without literally a month of getting approvals from various levels/depts of management and I'd need to repeat that process for each machine I want to install the software on so I can't install Alacritty or anything else for this.

ah, sad thing, then.

"I'd prefer to only use tput setb if I can for portability" - the only operands described by POSIX are clear, init and reset.

With mintty and MSYS2 MINGW64, any ANSI SGR color switching (for example with a colored prompt, or ls --color) resets the color set by tput setb 2. Even with PS1='\$ ', the screen needs to be cleared with clear, tput clear or by pressing Ctrl-L for it to be entirely with a light green background after tput setb 2; echo (parts of it stay black otherwise).

@Vilinkameni true regarding the POSIX tput spec but any tput I've had to use also supports setf, setb, etc. as described by POSIX.

@Vilinkameni thanks for the info on ls --color, etc., I never use that or any other color options for tools so I hadn't noticed that and now I see that printf '\e]11;#00FF00\a' doesn't have that issue so maybe using tput for this isn't the best approach after all. If I get an answer to the question I asked then I may post a followup about that one. Btw while tput clear does update the screen color (but obviously deletes the content, which isn't desirable in this case), typing or printing control-L does nothing except print a control-L.

About Ctrl-L, that could depend on the shell, whether it uses GNU Readline, and possibly TERM. I also just tested the behavior I described under Artix Linux, with Bash and xterm, with the exact same behavior as mintty. Also, under for example xfce4-terminal the background color isn't set at all with tput setb 2; echo, even after clearing the screen.

About the printf method, it "survives" ANSI SGR color switching, eg. from ls --color and setting PS1, etc. What's worth noting is that this holds true even in Artix Linux in xfce4-terminal.

What does \e]11 mean? In the man pages of console_codes(4), I can't find ESC ] 11;.

@aviro I hadn't come across it til today either when I saw it at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/474924/133219. The specific use of 11 and 10 are documented on page 34 of https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.pdf (Ps = 1 0 → Change VT100 text foreground color to Pt. and
Ps = 1 1 → Change VT100 text background color to Pt.). I now added a note about that to my question.

It seems to me it works like it should. OSC 11 changes the default background color for the console. tput setb uses CSI sequence, which overrides the default until being reset. That's also what ls / grep --color do, they change the color and then reset to the default. What exactly are you trying to achieve? How does this behavior bother you? I think what you show is the expected normal behavior.

@aviro I'm trying to get my terminal to have a background that's all 1 color using tput, It bothers me by leaving an undesirable (and so far not entirely explained) border of a different color around my terminal. Why is what I'm seeing, where one way of setting the background color (printf ...) does not leave a border of a different color while another way (tput ...) does leave a border of a different color, the expected/normal behavior given that the documentation I've found so far for both just say they set the background color?

What is you $TERM environment variable?

@aviro xterm.

Best I can tell from further reading and the discussion in the comments under my question the answer is - don't use tput setb 2 for this and use the printf approach instead:
printf '\e]11;#00FF00\a'

because:

The tput approach just sets the background color for the next thing you type while the printf does so for the whole terminal.
The tput approach leaves the border described in my question while the printf fills the whole terminal.
While you can get rid of the border by setting Padding=0 in ~/.minttyrc, you then have to restart the terminal to have that take effect and if/when you open the "Options" GUI to change anything else about the terminal then save it, it overwrites that minttyrc file and removes that Padding setting again.
The background set by the tput approach gets reset if/when you run a subsequent ls --color or other command that uses colors, while with the printf approach the background remains as desired.

